# Cannot install wireshark : error 1625 occurres while installing Visual C++ Redistributable

Tags: c++, installation, wireshark, redistributable

Wireshark 3.4.3 64bits installation fails on Windows 10 and indicates following error:

> The Visual C++ Redistributable installer failed with error 1625. Please make sure you have KB2999226 or KB3118401 installed. Unable to continue installation.

Meanwhile I can use the PortableApp version, but how can I install Wireshark successfully ?

Answer (score -1):

After two days, I could find the solution. I was helped by two observations:

1. A manual installation of Visual C++ Redistributable 2015-2019 also failed and mention policy limitation.
2. I also noticed that Visual Studio 2019 Community fails, especially the installation of `microsoft.visualstudio.minshell.msi.resources`.

After a quick search, I could find an online reference which suggest to disable Software Restriction Policy in the Local Security Policy. Here's what I did:

1. Search for "`Local Security Policy`" in the Windows menu, and click on the search result
2. Open the "`Software Restriction Policies`" in left menu. If it displays "`No Software Restrictions Defined`" in the right panel, just right-click the "`Software Restriction Policies`" on left menu and select "`New Software Restriction Policies`"
3. On right panel, double-click "`Enforcement`"
4. In the dialog, select "`All users except Local Administrators`" and click OK

After that, I could install both Wireshark and Visual Studio 2019 Community which both depend on Visual C++ Redistributable.

After successfull install, I rolled back my modifications in Local Security Strategy.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. I will lock for other solution.